# what does "pasting" and "cut" mean in function (topology)

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity, product-space

There is an example that explain this, but I still have 3 question:

Let $f: [0, 1] ∪] 2, 3]  → [0, 2]$ the application given by

$f (x) = x$         if $0 ≤ x ≤ 1$

$f(x)=x - 1$       if $2 <x ≤3$

Despite being bijective, $f$ is "pasting" the intervals $[0, 1]$ and$] 2, 3]$ in the interval $[0, 2]$, so $f^{−1}$ "Cut" this one at point $1$.

In general, if a continuous application is an application that does not cut, although
can paste, a homeomorphism is an application that does not cut or paste. For
that it does not paste has to be bijective, but we have just seen that this is not enough.

1. What does "pasting" and "cut" mean?
2. Why continuous function is an application that does not cut?
3. Why homeomorphism is an application that does not cut or paste?

Comment: Here, it's intended to be understood in naive meanings, so as to give you some intuition of continuous functions/homeomorphisms. Just imaging that each interval is a piece of [thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(yarn)). "Pasting" means gluing two threads at their ends. "Cut" means cutting a thread in the middle (e.g. with a pair of scissors). You may try to understand why these notions correspond to continuous functions/homeomorphisms, which will give you good intuition and thus deeper understanding of these abstract definitions.

Comment: but why doesn't the bijective function have to paste?

Comment: Intuitively because unpasting is cutting, and for a homeomorphism the inverse is also continuous. This example was useful to illustrate that a continuous bijection may fail to be a homeomorphism.

Comment: There you have to understand that we are talking about an application of a space in its image, so the superjectivity is given in advance. If it is not injective, it means that two different points have the same image, then the starting space is transformed into another in which two different points are glued into one.

For example, consider $f: [0,1] ⟶S^1$ given by $f (t) = (cos (2πt), sin (2πt))$. It is a continuous application that transforms a segment into a circle by gluing its two ends together, since they both have the same image on the circumference.

Comment: Then the function f is a continuous function that is not bijective since in f (0) = f (1), then it pastes the segment at its ends (because it is of the form f ([0,1]) = S ^ 1) , and since it pastes the ends of the segment then its inverse function cuts, therefore the inverse function is not continuous, so it is not a homeomorphism. Is this analysis correct?

Comment: You can make $f$ bijective by making the domain $[0,1)$ instead (or $(0,1]$, it is not important). Then you have a continuous bijection that isn't a homeomorphism. Without doing that it doesn't make sense to talk about the inverse anyway.

Comment: Thank you all for your response, I already understood what you were consulting initially.